# How to change the appearance of Jupiter Notebook to default

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been using Jupiter notebook for a moment, but for some reason, the menu of my Notebook changed to something that looks like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuy7Q.png)

However, I have difficulties finding my marks with this menu. I would like to know how to change it back to the more classic setting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this website.

I just had to run the following command

```
!jt -r
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).